# Getting data from MATLAB Simulink every 0.008s in .txt file

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

I need to get data from my simulink model, write it to txt file, have another program read it, and this every 0.008s.

Is there any way to do it? All i could get is to get data into workspace

Also the system is discrete

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [To File block](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/tofile.html) to save the data to disk. It will figure out the correct buffer size, etc., for you and write the data to disk. You just have to poll from the other program to get new data.

8 milliseconds is generally not enough data to justify the overhead of disk IO, so the To File block needs more than this to write to disk, and your other program needs more than this to read. This obviously introduces latency.

If you want a lower-latency solution, consider using UDP or TCP comminication blocks that exist in the DSP System Toolbox libarary.

Comment: The To File block only writes when the simultion is paused or terminates, it does not write at each time step.  And even if it did, there is no way, on a non-real time OS (which all Simulink supports) that you will get a 8ms sample rate.  You need to convert the model to C (using Simulink Coder) and run the code on a real-time OS.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Looks like it writes a file during the simulation to me... I can connect a "From Audio Device" block to a "To File" block and watch the file size gradually increase as the simulation is run. And a sample rate of 8ms is nothing, as long as you read/write in blocks.

Comment: Yes, my mistake -- the To Workspace block writes on pause and termination while the To File write incrementally during the simulation.  Note however that it writes to a .mat file not a txt file as requested by the OP.  I still disagree with you about guaranteeing sample rates of 8ms on a non-real time OS.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's impossible to say anything without a lot more detail.

How much data? What operating system? What happens if you "miss"? What kind of disk is the file on? Does it *really* have to be a file on-disk, can't you use e.g. pipes or something to avoid hitting disk? What does the "other program" have to do with the data?

8 milliseconds is not a lot of time for a disk to do anything, you're basically going to be assuming all accesses are in cache in order to work, so factor out the disk. Use a pipe or a RAM disk.

8 milliseconds is also not a lot of time for a typical desktop operating system.

Comment: Basically i need to get speed from my simulink model to regulate virtual robot, and the robot sends me its current positon to for simlink model, that's the control loop Size od the data is just speed in m/s, operating system is windows 7, problem is that the other program can only read and write data in txt file, and 8ms is because of the frequency of robot